# ROR: Adding a colums to user table: Unpermitted parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, database-migration

I am new to rails so please excuse my not so good explanation. Im working with the gem Devise. I have email and password set up correctly. I now want to add a username. So what I did was:

```
rails g migration AddUserNameToUsers Username:string

  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20170203113948_add_user_name_to_users.rb
```

Then:

```
rails db:migrate
== 20170203113948 AddUserNameToUsers: migrating   
-- add_column(:users, :Username, :string)
-> 0.0017s
== 20170203113948 AddUserNameToUsers: migrated (0.0024s)
```

Then I checked it was added to the users table:

```
sqlite> select * from users;
13|Username|varchar|0||0
```

Then I set up the devise registration view to include username:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :email %><br />
                <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
              </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :Username %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :Username, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :password %> <% if @validatable %><i>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</i><% end %><br />
                <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
                <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
              </div>
            <% end %>
```

The page came back with no errors when I submit the form but the username was not added. And the logs show:

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2017-02-03 12:43:40 +0000
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"MfdDSafryl0mnHM3BzEtxkOoImZXUm7rfcq2sYrNaltD2S8i3SvFCRdMqam9ukEZXcY23zF/NpY/LPyj6tJm2A==", "user"=>{"email"=>"joe@test.com", "Username"=>"james", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
 Unpermitted parameter: Username
```

Comment: You need to permit Username attibute, follow http://jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html , this may help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I had the method in the wrong controller to start of with.